# What temperature can oyster mushrooms withstand?

Tags: mushrooms

I accidentally left my oyster mushroom kit in a very warm area (maybe up to 120) for a week, and the kit seems to not be showing anything after having it for 2 weeks. Should I be worried about it not growing?

My shiitake were exposed to the same environmental conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the car one week only hot in daylight hours they should be fine the substrate is wood which would insulate you could have stressed them which shows up as a golden brown yellow in the block give it a little extra time or just get another.

Comment: I would love a follow-up to this because from what I've read, temps above 110, even for just a few hours, prove lethal to oyster mushroom mycelium. In my experience mycelium vigor has been permanently inhibited from ambient temps in the high 80s and low 90s.